# Adding classes to list items based on theirs child's ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to achieve something like this using jQuery:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#id-220" class="id-220 id-320 id-321 id-322">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id-320" class="id-320 id-321 id-322">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id-321" class="id-321 id-322">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id-322" class="id-322">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I have only this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#id-220">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id-320">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id-321">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#id-322">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, basically I want that each list item is looking for its sibling's ID and add them by order as class. First list item has 3 siblings, and by that it must have 4 classes (his own and 3 from siblings) and so on ... I hope that I explained it well... TNX!

Comment: You can start with showing some code..

Comment: In your example, none of the `li` elements have children. Do you mean siblings following it? Or is the html wrong?

Comment: Yea I am sorry ... I just waked up, I meant siblings, tnx for the info Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul id="mainUL">
        <li><a href="#id-220">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#id-320">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#id-321">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#id-322">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
        var As = $("#mainUL").find("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < As.length; i++) {
            var curAi = $(As[i]);
            var clas = curAi.attr("href").replace("#", "");
            for (var j = i; j < As.length; j++) {
                var curAj = $(As[j]);
                clas += " " + curAj.attr("href").replace("#", "");
            }
            curAi.addClass(clas);
        }

</script>
```

I know there could be more efficient and better solutions too. But this one is running fine for me without any bug, Worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('li').each(function(){
                cls = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                cls1 = cls.replace("#", '');
                curli = this;
                $(curli).addClass(cls1);
                $(this).nextAll('li').each(function() {
                    cls = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
                    cls1 = cls.replace("#", '');
                    $(curli).addClass(cls1);
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var $activeLI = $(this);
    $activeLI.addClass($activeLI.find('a').attr('href').substring(1));

    $activeLI.nextAll('li').each(function() {
        $activeLI.addClass($(this).find('a').attr('href').substring(1))
    });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ypQ2e/)

Comment: I tried to put your code but I had some errors. I needed to modify it cause it didnt find attr('href') because no anchor was specified: activeLI.find('a').attr('href'). But, still is not working: <li class="id-220 id-320">
<li class="id-320 id-321">
<li class="id-321 id-322">
<li class="id-322">

Comment: I've edited my answer and now should work ok.. this method is more accurate because you use just jQuery.. not any pure js

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
    lastli = $('ul > li:last');
    lastli.children('a').addClass( lastli.children('a').attr('href').replace('#','') );
    while (lastli.prev().length) {
       prevli = lastli.prev();
       prevli.children('a').addClass( lastli.children('a').attr('class') );
       prevli.children('a').addClass( prevli.children('a').attr('href').replace('#','') );
       lastli = prevli;
     }
```

See working [**demo**](https://tinker.io/26b85/1)

Answer (score 0):

One more variant:

```
function setClasses() {
    var className = "";
    $.each($("li > a").get().reverse(), function(index, item) {
        className += $(item).attr("href").replace(/^#/, "") + " ";
        $(item).addClass(className);        
    });
}

setClasses();
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dbASG/3/).